# Transform dataset to multilevel adjacency matrix (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, network-programming

For multilevel network analysis, I need my adjacency matrix to be *multilevel*. This means I want to paste my Z01 to Z09 variables (adjacency matrix per class) into my X130101 to X130208 (between classes frame) according to the values in my W variable.

**W = unique code for a pupil**

**X = pupil number in a specific class**

**Y = class number**

**Z = variables that indicate if a pupil likes another person in his/her class.** A 1 for Z04 means he/she likes person 4 of his/her class. If 130101 in my example dataset likes 130104, then s/he will have a 1 in the Z04 column. However, some people are missing in the dataset. 130102 for example did not participate.

I need code to make a matrix where for every pupil, the values of the Z columns, are pasted in the X130101:X130208 columns. For every pupil in class 1301, the Z01,Z03,Z04,Z05,Z08,Z09 values need to be pasted in X130101:X130109. All values between students from different classes will be zero, but this is the format I need.

In my example dataset, it's only 2 classes and 12 rows. In my real dataset, I have more than 300 classes and 6300 rows...

I am not that familiar with coding in R so I was wondering if people had any idea how to approach this? *

*I guess I need to iterate through "W" where I want the values between Z01 and Z09 be pasted in the columns that match my row in W (without the X before the number), but not from the Z01:Z09 variables that are missing in my W variable (if 130102 is missing, do not use data of Z02 in that class).*

This is what I want in a picture: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOh6E.png) (I am new and can't upload picture directly)

```
dataframe5 <- data.frame(
w = c(130101,130103,130104,130105,130108,130109,  130201,130202,130204,130206,130207,130208), 
x = c(1,3,4,5,8,9,  1,2,4,6,7,8), 
y = c(1301,1301,1301,1301,1301,1301,  1302,1302,1302,1302,1302,1302), 

z01 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0,1),
z02 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,0,0),
z03 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,1,0),
z04 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0,1),
z05 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 1,1,0,1,0,0),
z06 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,0,0),
z07 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,0,0),
z08 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1,0,0),
z09 = c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,0,1), 

X130101 = 0,X130103 =0 ,X130104 =0, X130105=0,X130108=0,X130109=0,X130201=0,X130202=0,X130204=0,X130206=0,X130207=0,X130208=0)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi, I have just included a picture which would make it a bit easier to see :)